# Unfortunately, sudoku has stopped

Tags: java, android, sudoku

I'm new programming in Android and I'm reading "Hello, Android" book, 3rd edition. The second chapter is a tutorial about making a sudoku. Even with the code from the book, when I run the program, it install in the AVD but suddenly, it says "Unfortunately, sudoku has stopped". I have searched in the Internet without solution.

The code is the following:

***main.xlm***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@string/main_title" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@string/continue_label" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@string/new_game_label" />
    <Button 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@string/about_label" />
    <Button 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@string/exit_label" />
</LinearLayout>
```

---

***Sudoku.java***

```
package org.example.sudoku;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class Sudoku extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

---

***AndroidManifest.xlm***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.example.sudoku"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Main"
            android:label="@string/main_title" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

---

the ***logcat*** is:

```
08-22 22:28:38.333: I/Process(610): Sending signal. PID: 610 SIG: 9
08-22 22:28:58.142: E/Trace(653): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
08-22 22:28:58.492: D/AndroidRuntime(653): Shutting down VM
08-22 22:28:58.492: W/dalvikvm(653): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
08-22 22:28:58.503: E/AndroidRuntime(653): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-22 22:28:58.503: E/AndroidRuntime(653): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{org.example.sudoku/org.example.sudoku.Main}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.example.sudoku.Main
08-22 22:28:58.503: E/AndroidRuntime(653):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1983)
08-22 22:28:58.503: E/AndroidRuntime(653):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
08-22 22:28:58.503: E/AndroidRuntime(653):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
08-22 22:28:58.503: E/AndroidRuntime(653):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
08-22 22:28:58.503: E/AndroidRuntime(653):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-22 22:28:58.503: E/AndroidRuntime(653):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-22 22:28:58.503: E/AndroidRuntime(653):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
08-22 22:28:58.503: E/AndroidRuntime(653):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-22 22:28:58.503: E/AndroidRuntime(653):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-22 22:28:58.503: E/AndroidRuntime(653):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
08-22 22:28:58.503: E/AndroidRuntime(653):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-22 22:28:58.503: E/AndroidRuntime(653):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-22 22:28:58.503: E/AndroidRuntime(653): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.example.sudoku.Main
08-22 22:28:58.503: E/AndroidRuntime(653):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
08-22 22:28:58.503: E/AndroidRuntime(653):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
08-22 22:28:58.503: E/AndroidRuntime(653):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
08-22 22:28:58.503: E/AndroidRuntime(653):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
08-22 22:28:58.503: E/AndroidRuntime(653):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1974)
08-22 22:28:58.503: E/AndroidRuntime(653):  ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 4):

Edit following line in AndroidManifest.xml

```
android:name=".Main"
```

as

```
android:name=".Sudoku"
```